# Entity Framework select single item of navigations navigation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am unsure on what to search for and therefore couldn't get an answer for this.

I have the following setup:

```
public class CommunitySubForum
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public Int32 DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public Int32 ParentForumId { get; set; }
    public virtual CommunityForum ParentForum { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CommunityThread> Threads { get; set; }
}

public class CommunityThread
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEdited { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsLocked { get; set; }
    public Int32 ParentForumId { get; set; }
    public virtual CommunitySubForum ParentForum {get;set;}
    public virtual List<CommunityPost> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual MLUser MlUser { get; set; }
    public Int32 MLUserId { get; set; }
}

public class CommunityPost
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EditDate { get; set; }
    public Int32 ThreadId { get; set; }
    public virtual CommunityThread Thread { get; set; }
    public virtual MLUser MlUser{ get; set; }
    public Int32 MLUserId { get; set; }
    public Int32 MediaItemParentId { get; set; }
    public BaseMediaItem MediaItem { get; set; }
}
```

Now, what I am trying to do is, get the thread with the newest post in a subforum.

Getting the newest thread is no problem but I am unsure on how to get the thread for the newest post in a performant way. Preferably with lambda.

Obviously I could just get the newest post and get the thread to it and add it to my subforum obj in a separate query but I am looking to get it in a single query.

Edit: I need to get a list of all Subforums with a thread in it that has the newest post. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6B6y.png

Comment: Do a `JOIN` between your entities. first get the newest post join with thread and then join with subforum.

Comment: Sorry, I misunterstood your question. This code is to get the subforum that contains the newest post. `var forumWithLatestPost = DbContext<CommunityPost>().OrderBy(p => p.CreationDate).Last().Select(p => p.Thread.ParentForum)`. But you want to define in which subforum to search, right?

Comment: you mean the newest post of any posts? Won't there just be a single subforum containing this post? Why do you need a list of subforums?

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider You can think of a list on a forum that lists all subforums with a link to the thread with the newest post in it.
Basically like this: http://i.imgur.com/8RHvqxK.png

 I do not have a constructor for DbContext<T> ?

Comment: Then the answers of Yacoub Massad is what you are looking for. And you are right, it should read `DbContext.Set<CommunityPost>` or `DbContext.CommunityPost`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
var result =
    subforums
    .Select(sf => new 
    {
        SubForum = sf,
        MostRecentPost = 
            sf.Threads
            .SelectMany(t => t.Posts)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreateDate)
            .FirstOrDefault()

    })
    .ToList();
```

This query will get you a list of anonymous typed objects that contain the  `CommunitySubForum` objects with the corresponding latest `CommunityPost` object.

If you are just interested in some of the properties of these objects you could easily modify the query to select specific properties.

If you want the most recent threads instead, you could simply use `Select` to select the `Thread` or any of its properties like this:

```
var result =
    subforums
    .Select(sf => new 
    {
        SubForum = sf,
        MostRecentThread = 
            sf.Threads
            .SelectMany(t => t.Posts)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreateDate)
            .Select(p => p.Thread)
            .FirstOrDefault()

    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Guess this is better than mine. The OP could use `MostRecentPost.Thread` to display `Thread` info. (I saw the image later).

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold. Also, selecting the thread can be done through the same SQL query. I updated my answer to include this.

Comment: Uh I am getting the error {"Unknown column 'Extent1.Id' in 'where clause'"}

Comment: I am not really sure why you have this error. I have tested the code I posted and it works fine. You could use SQL profiler to see the SQL query that is generated. This can help you troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Collect the newest post date for each threads, and then order the threads by this newest post date to get the most recent one:

```
from f in Subforums
select new
{
    f.Title,
    ThreadWithNewestPost = (
                               from t in f.Threads
                               select new
                               {
                                   t.Title,
                                   NewestPostDate = t.Posts.Max(p => p.CreateDate )
                               }
                           ).OrderByDescending(x => x.NewestPostDate)
                            .FirstOrDefault()
}
```

I assume that `Thread`s always have `Posts`, otherwise you should check for that in the query.